# What are alternatives to Device Anywhere for Mobile Web Testing?

Tags: tools, mobile, web

I am looking for alternative tools to Device Anywhere that offer carrier access. This is for mobile web testing (NOT Web App).

My Question:

1. What are some alternative tools to Device Anywhere that offer debug information such as access to the website source, similar to Chrome or Safari?

Answer (score 2):

The working alternative is the following combination:

> [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/) + [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) + [Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/)

How-to guide can be found here: http://kodedistiller.net/2013/11/16/weinre-on-azure-in-combination-with-browserstack/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to debug a mobile website. The first few ways are provided by Apple and Google and allow you to connect your mobile device to your computer and use Safari and Chrome's development tools to see the source of the application.

Apple: Enable Web Inspector through the Settings > Safari settings on the device and then use Safari on the desktop to inspect the elements.

Google: Enable the developer options on the device, install drivers if needed on the desktop, and then launch Chrome on the desktop and navigate to about:inspect and connect to the device with the DevTools .

Another way is to use testing tools made by the company I work for, Mobile Labs. We provide a private secure mobile testing cloud (an alternative to Device Anywhere) called deviceConnect as well as an automated testing tool that provides the ability to test mobile websites, web apps, hybrid apps, as well as native apps.

You can learn more here: http://mobilelabsinc.com/solutions/

Comment: I appreciate the answer, we already use the Apple and Google's provided tools, however we require access to actual carrier networks and Safari/Chrome level debug information.

Answer (score 0):

If you've been looking for an alternative tool for mobile web testing, then try out [LT Browser](https://www.producthunt.com/posts/lt-browser-2). Recently, I came across this tool on product hunt as it was ranked as the 5th product of the day. It's a developer-oriented desktop tool to conduct responsive mobile web testing across more than 45+ pre-installed devices. Also, you can perform mobile-view debugging on different resolutions simultaneously.
You can conduct live collaborative testing of web apps to ensure responsiveness across multiple smartphones in a side-by-side view.

Here are some cool features about LT Browser that I liked the most:

It offers various features, few of them are:

- Performance Report of your websites powered by Google Lighthouse.
- Full-paged screenshots of your websites.
- Website testing over different network conditions such as fast 3g,
  slow 3g, or offline.
- Scroll-sync to compare your website simultaneously on different devices.
- Touch mode for scrolling.
- Ability to add custom devices.

Try it out Hope this helps!